# stop,start and destroy interval when new window or new tab is open in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have interval which works correctly and destroys well but when I navigate to new window or new tab, the alert is also shown there. How to stop this alert?

```
$scope.checkGuest = function() {
  $http.get(url + 'c_chat/checkGuestJson').success(function (data) {
    $scope.guestAlerts = data
    console.log(data);
    if(data == 1) {
      alert('plz register to enjoy more features');
    } 
    else {
      alert('plz register ! after 10 minutes your contact will be deleted');
    }
  })
}
```

I have set interval like this for 11 minutes

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
  $scope.checkGuest() 
}, 660000);      

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { 
  $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); 
})
```

When route is changed the alert is not shown which is right but when new tab is open the alert is shown which I DO NOT LIKE

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/c_chat', {
     template: '<div class="gusestAlert"></div>',
     controller: app.chatCtrl
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

well the problem here is that that `$destroy` listener is  not triggered if you open a link in a new tab because that scope for angular is still "alive".

what you can do here is to force the call to the listener every time a new tab is open.

for example

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', destroyInterval); //called by angular
$rootScope.$on('$destroyInterval', destroyInterval); //generic listener

function destroyInterval(){ 
  $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); 
})

<a href="/something" target="_blank" ng-click="$root.$emit('$destroyInterval') ">
  go to new tab </a>
```